# When I reload the page the text that I put in my text boxes stays there, can I make this not happen?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am in HTML5 with Javascript as well and my code looks like this.

#### Your phrase

```
  <textarea type="text" name="phrase" id="phrase" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Write your text here. . ."></textarea>
```

I would like the text to go away upon reload. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing your browser is Firefox. Well for this you can write a script in your page.

```
    <script language="javascript">            

        window.onload = function(e) {
           $('#phrase').val("");
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $('textarea').val('')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to remove `text`.

```js
document.getElementById("phrase").textContent="";
```

```html
<textarea type="text" name="phrase" id="phrase" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Write your text here. . .">text that stays</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is working. However I did go ahead and try on chrome and it does what I want on there. Must be caching it. Oh well. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.onload = function() {
$get("phrase").value='';
};
```